# javascript iframe crossDomain

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I want to send a `CROSSDOMAIN` POST REQUEST.

I create a hidden iframe and form to get the result:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");           
var iframeName = "crossDoamin";           
iframe.style.display = "none";           
iframe.name = iframeName;             
document.body.appendChild(iframe);             

var form = document.createElement("form");     
form.action = "http://xxxxxxxxx.action";    
form.method = "POST";     
form.target = iframeName;     
form.style.display = "none";     

//repeat for each parameter     
var input_pid = document.createElement("input");    
input_pid.name = "xxx";     
input_pid.value = xxx;     
form.appendChild(input_pid);               
document.body.appendChild(form); 
form.submit();
```

and now, when I use javascript to get the innerHTML of iframe like

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document
```

it turns out the problem that `protocal doamin and .. must match`

How can I get the innerHTML of the hidden iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can't! when your window is served over HTTPS you can't include resources which are served over HTTP without having the browser display a warning. It's for the user's security!

You might be able to work around this limitation by calling another script on your site which in turn will call make the POST call and return the HTML content you're looking for. Just an idea - I never tested it...